# Linux Web Server Dosen't always allow external connections

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, webserver, port-forwarding

I have been having this problem with where it will allow external connections for about 30 minutes but then doesn't allow any? I have port forwarded and all that. I turned it on last night and I wouldn't allow external connections but I came home today and turned it on and it would for 30 minutes but then it stopped so i restarted it and shut it down and booted up again but it still wouldn't allow them again?

My ISP is **TalkTalk**

Comment: We need more information... What do you have to do to make it accept connections again? Restart the server, reboot, restart your router, just wait?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Is it a Webserver you are maintaining? or a home-PC?

Comment: its an old computer that i turned into a webserver and its at home so its nothing big

Comment: How are you trying to connect to the server? In particular, trying to connect from a machine inside your network using the public IP address sometimes causes problems. Have you tried with the local IP address?

Comment: im trying to connect on my phone using 3G (therefor outside my local network) and using my public IP